# How to calculate number of viewer and store them in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, viewstate

I am making a eCommerce web application.I want that whenever a new user click on the product, the number of viewer get increased by one.
My Product table has columns

```
ProductID,ProductName,Description,Quantity,Price,SubCategoryID(Foreign Key)
```

should i add a new column 'Viewers' in it with datatype int.

How to do the code in asp.net with c#.
So that on clickevent of product the viewer get increase by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Set the product title was a link button ,

and whenever the user click the linkbutton add to database !!

for the product view is first time : 0 , whenever the user click the product title , then we add +1 with database .

See this : http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/shopping-cart

http://thebeerhouse.codeplex.com/